# Passing UTM Parameters to Intercom

Tags: jquery, cookies, intercom

I am trying to pass UTM parameters to Intercom to track users who chat with us and where they are coming from.

Intercom recommends capturing that information and setting it with the jQuery cookies plugin. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.intercom.com/configure-intercom-for-your-product-or-site/customize-intercom-to-be-about-your-users/track-conversions-and-clicks-with-utm-parameters).

I am using the latest release of Cookies and updated the code Intercom provides just a bit.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../js/js.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getURLParam(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(window.location.search) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if(getURLParam('utm_source') !== null) {
    Cookies.set('utm_source', getURLParam('utm_source'), {
      expires: 365,
      path: '/',
      domain: window.location.hostname,
      secure: true
    });
  }

  if(getURLParam('utm_campaign') !== null) {
    Cookies.set('utm_campaign', getURLParam('utm_campaign'), {
      expires: 365,
      path: '/',
      domain: window.location.hostname,
      secure: true
    });
  }

  if(getURLParam('utm_medium') !== null) {
    Cookies.set('utm_medium', getURLParam('utm_medium'), {
      expires: 365,
      path: '/',
      domain: window.location.hostname,
      secure: true
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

I know this is working correctly because using the Javascript console in Chrome Developer Tools, I can call

```
Cookies.get('utm_source')
```

and get the actual value if the URL contains that particular UTM parameter.

But for some reason, this is not passing to Intercom and the code (located in the footer) for passing that information looks like:

```
<script>
  window.intercomSettings = {
   app_id: "zto7cy6x",
   "utm_source": Cookies.get('utm_source'),
   "utm_medium": Cookies.get('utm_medium'),
   "utm_campaign": Cookies.get('utm_campaign')
  };
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the intercom script following the settings?
Simply having the `window.intercomSettings` variable difined is not enough. You must also have the intercom script that sends out those settings to intercom.

```
<script>
    window.intercomSettings = {
       app_id: "zto7cy6x",
       "utm_source": Cookies.get('utm_source'),
       "utm_medium": Cookies.get('utm_medium'),
       "utm_campaign": Cookies.get('utm_campaign')
    };
</script>
<script>(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/wprz7ktj';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()</script>
```

Comment: The Intercom script is indeed after the window.intercomSettings variable.

Comment: Might be good to for you to remove your `app_id` from your example :)

Comment: That part is just a copy-paste from the OP